# how to save a text on the image view with the different fonts?

Tags: android, text, fonts, android-gridview

i want to save a text on the image view with the different fonts automatically on the image view .as soon as the user type the text .the text should be correctly fit on the image view with the different fonts .here is my code

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private SharedPreferences prefs;
private EditText editText;
private Button btn;
private SeekBar seek;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    seek=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    prefs=getSharedPreferences("test", MODE_PRIVATE);
    //prefs=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor ed=prefs.edit();
    ed.putFloat("Fontsize",editText.getTextSize());
    ed.putString("text", editText.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "saved Sucessfully",        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
float fontsize  =prefs.getFloat("Fontsize", 12);
    seek.setProgress((int)fontsize);
    editText.setText(prefs.getString("text", ""));
    editText.setTextSize(seek.getProgress());
    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            editText.setTextSize(seek.getProgress());

        }
    });

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.grid);

            GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

            // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
            gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this));

           gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
            // passing array index
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

put the edittext and imageview in relative layout. This will overlap them. You can adjust the marigins/padding then.

Comment: My problem is that as soon as the app opens the user types his text and save and in the next intent he would the image in grid view and in next intent the text should get saved on the image with the different fonts